# Selenium webdriver table parsing php using RemoteWebdriver instance?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Hello Friends I want to fetch information from table 
My structure is:

```
<table>
                   <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="seo-company-label">Name</td>
                        <td class="seo-company-data">LinkedIn Corporation</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="seo-company-label">Website</td>
                        <td class="seo-company-data">
                             <a target="_blank" href="[enter link description here][1]">
                              Rakesh
                             </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="seo-company-label">Headquarters</td>
                        <td class="seo-company-data">
                            2029 Stierlin Ct<br>
                            Mountain View, CA  94043-4655<br>
                            United States&nbsp;
                           <a target="_blank" href="[enter link description here][2]">map</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="seo-company-label">Phone</td>
                        <td class="seo-company-data">+1.650.687.3600</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="seo-company-label">Industries</td>
                        <td class="seo-company-data">
                               Software &amp; Internet, E-commerce and Internet Businesses<br>
                                Software &amp; Internet, Data Analytics, Management and Storage<br>Business Services, HR and Recruiting Services
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="seo-company-label">Employees</td>
                        <td class="seo-company-data">
                               1K - 10K
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="seo-company-label">Revenue</td>
                        <td class="seo-company-data">
                               &gt; $1B
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="seo-company-label">Ownership</td>
                        <td class="seo-company-data">Publicly Traded   
                             - NASDAQ : <a title="LNKD" target="_blank" href="[www.facebook.com][3]">LNKD</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody> </table>
```

Here I want to fetch information from each row along with its td details if its containces anchro tag then its href pls help me.

My Code is :

```
$host = 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub'; // this is the default
$capabilities = array(WebDriverCapabilityType::BROWSER_NAME => 'GOOGLECHROME');
$driver = RemoteWebDriver::create($host, $capabilities,1000);
$driver->get('http://www.xyz.com/');
$input = $driver->findElement(
WebDriverBy::id('freeTextInput')
);
  $input->sendKeys($query_string)->submit();
$row_result = $driver->findElements(WebDriverBy::cssSelector('.seo-company-info table tbody tr'));   
for($i=0;$i<count($row_result);$i++)
{
  sleep(5);
  $cells_result = $row_result[$i]->findElements(WebDriverBy::tagName('td'));
  for($j=0;$i<count($cells_result);$j++)
  {
    echo $ranks = $cells_result[$j]->findElement(WebDriverBy::className(''))->geTtext();
    //$company = $cells_result[$j]->findElement(WebDriverBy::className(''))->geTtext();
  }//cells end..
}//rows end..
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm rusty on PHP, but it should be something like this...

```
foreach($results as $row)
{
  $cells = $row->findElements(WebDriverBy::tagName('td'));
  //Do something with the cells here
}
```